# unable find location of kernel debian package in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

Actually I was able to find the kernel Debian package(/pool/main/l/linux-signed-hwe-*/linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic_5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1_amd64.deb) in ubuntu-20.04 iso image, But Now, I checked the same directory(/pool/main/l/) kernel Debian package not found in ubuntu-22.04. Then where is the kernel Debian package in the ubuntu-22.04 iso image

Comment: The 5.13 kernel was from Ubuntu 21.10 which is EOL, it's *unsupported* having been for some now now.  It was a HWE kernel also used by 20.04, but was replaced with the GA kernel from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ie. 5.15.  The 5.13 kernel is no longer used (*unpatched for security flaws being unsupported*) why are you after it?

Comment: I install ubuntu manually from liveCD to the hard disk. So, I want kernel image from ISO image